# Initializing an array of pointers in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, struct, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have a pretty specific data structure issue that I cannot figure out.  For my assignment, I must have a dynamically allocated array of structures in my private section of my header.  So, up to this point, in my header file, I have

```
struct node{
  int name;
  node *next;};
```

In my private, I have

```
node *adj;
```

which is, at least to my knowledge, how you would set up having the array.
Then, in my .cpp file, I have

```
adj = new node*[];
```

This is throwing a bunch of errors.  But, when I have

```
node *adj[n];
```

in my cpp and nothing in my header, it works.  My questions is how do I have an array in my private section of my header, but dynamically allocate the space in my .cpp?

Comment: `node *adj;` is not an array of pointers, it is a pointer to `node`.  `node **adg` would be an array of pointers.

Comment: @EdS. The title says array of pointers, the text says array of structures. Having thought about it I guess an array of pointers is what is really required.

Comment: @john: Yeah, I was going off of this: `adj = new node*[];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have defined

```
node *adj;
```

which is a pointer to a node, or an array of nodes.  If you want an array of pointers to nodes, you should declare

```
node **adj;
```

which is a pointer to a pointer to a node, or an array of pointers to nodes.  In the first case, you allocate the array using

```
adj = new node[n];
```

which defines an array of nodes. and in the second you use

```
adj = new node*[n];
```

which defines an array of node pointers.

```
adj = new node*[];
```

should not make sense as it does not tell the compiler how big to make the array.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed.  The second version worked perfectly.